# Using array in the JQuery

Tags: jquery

In my application , i am having a code like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).each(function() { 
          type= "<?=$r['Attribute']['type'];?>";
          attribute_id= "<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>";
          if(type=="dropdown")
          {
               var ht = $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/viewChoices/"+attribute_id,
                   async: false
               }).responseText;


               var myObject = eval('(' + ht + ')');
               alert(myObject);


               // var getchoice=myObject.choices[0]["choice"];
               //alert(getchoice);

                                                    }
        });
     }):
```

In the above code for each attributeid , i am seeing whether the type of its is a Dropdown then i am retriving its choices from that Ajax get from the Table Choices in the choice,
My myObject displays like

```
   {"choices":[{"choice":"Male"},{"choice":"Female"}]}//for a attribute with the label gender

   {"choices":[{"choice":"BE"},{"choice":"ME"},{"choice":"MBA"}]}//for a attribute with the label qualification
```

But that getChoice displays only male , and later be since i am using [0]

i want to keep these first alerted values that is male and female in an array 
And then in the same array later to save only be,me,mba ..
Because i want to keep these array values to be displayed in the dropdown box for the respective labels ...How to do so.......Please sugggest me...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that you could improve:

1 . Using each with an [id selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id).

```
$("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).each
```

Using `each` doesn't makes sense, since this selector will match a single element, and the element id must be unique.

2 . $.ajax for handling a JSON response

If you are doing an ajax request that returns JSON, the [$.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) function is the best way to go, you don't have to parse the responce, it will be safely evaluated by jQuery.

3 . Your request is synchronous.

I'm not against synchronous requests, but I think that you don't explicitly need it.

Finally, for your JSON response, you could easily flatten the result, using the [$.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) function for example:

```
var data = {"choices":[{"choice":"Male"},{"choice":"Female"}]};
$.map(data.choices, function(i){return i.choice;}); 
// returns ["Male", "Female"]
```